# Blender disappeared after upgrading my Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 - unmet dependency error for installing it

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, 15.10, dependencies, blender

[image]
Here is the screen-shot of the error.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text and apply code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` which probably contains the reference to the ppa repository of blender. The third argument in the line has to be `vivid` for version 15.04 and `wily` for version 15.10. Probably, you are mixing software and libraries from both versions.